# Sessão não abre ao fazer login

Tags: php, mysqli, session, login

Estou alterando um antigo projeto de admin, consegui trocar a senhas de sha1 para password_hash, porém a sessão não abre mais ao logar. O que pode estar acontecendo? Já procurei e não encontrei solução.

```php
$sql = "SELECT `id`, `nome`, `nivel` FROM `usuarios` WHERE (`usuario` = '". $usuario ."') AND (`ativo` = 1) LIMIT 1";
$query = mysqli_query($conexao, $sql);

$senhabd = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
if(password_verify($senha, $senhabd['senha'])){

if (mysqli_num_rows($query) != 1) {

echo "<script>document.location='../login.php'; alert('Login Inválido! Tente novamente.')</script>";
     exit;

} else {

    $resultado = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);

    if (!isset($_SESSION)) session_start();
```

Comment: além de id, nome, nivel, não teria que colocar também  'senha' na query?

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo Quando era sha1 estava na query, porém o password_verify é booleano, não sei como faz essa comparação dentro da query.

Comment: @LucasGuse, você mencionou que trocou as senhas para sha1, como você fez este processo? Você implementou a hash a partir do método password_hash do PHP?

Comment: @DiegoMiranda Isso, no cadastro dos usuários troquei a senha para password_hash e deu tudo certo, no login ele aceita e redireciona. Mas as páginas tem verificação de login e acaba dando erro, me parece que a Sessão não está sendo aberta.

Comment: Esse é o código que vai nas páginas para verificar o login?

Comment: @LucasGuse, deste trecho de código atualizado, o usuário é realmente obtido para a comparação das senhas? A verificação do número de registros obtidos não deveria se encontrar antes da verficação das senhas?

Comment: @TiagoA essa é a validação do login, a das páginas é diferente.

Comment: @DiegoMiranda, consegui resolver :)
Estava tendo um problema na chamada da senha no banco de dados, estava comparando com a primeira senha que tinha na bd ao invés de pegar a do usuário. Obrigado.